# Playwright Vercel Error: browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1067/chrome-linux/chrome

Tags: node.js, next.js, deployment, vercel, playwright

I tried and tested on a different local environment like Windows, Linux, mac and everywhere it works fine but once I deploy my nextjs app on Vercel, I'm getting the below error

```
browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1067/chrome-linux/chrome
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
║                                                                         ║
║     npx playwright install                                              ║
║                                                                         ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
    at pdf (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/jobOrders/pdf.js:58:80)
    at pdfHandler (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/jobOrders/pdf.js:91:31) {
  name: 'Error'
}
```

To resolve this issue, I tried modifying the build command in Vercel deployment settings to

```
next build && npx playwright install
```

[image]

[image]
[image]
While I see the browsers like Chrome and firefox getting installed successfully, still I wonder why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Stuff like your package.json should be text. It's unhelpful to expect people to retype it or use OCR just to get the text and be able to reproduce your environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should run tests before deploying your application during the CI phase. Production deployment should only proceed after all tests have been successfully completed.

However, you can use Vercel's webhooks with your Git provider to run an end-to-end test suite after your Vercel deployment has finished. This example will use GitHub Actions.

#### Configure a GitHub Action

1. Connect your Git repository to your project. For new projects, you can [follow these docs](https://vercel.com/docs/deployments/git#deploying-a-git-repository). For existing projects, visit your Git configuration in the Settings tab of your project dashboard.
2. Create a GitHub workflow in `.github/workflows` with the following:

```yaml
name: Playwright Tests

on:
  deployment_status:
jobs:
  run-e2es:
    if: github.event_name == 'deployment_status' && github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npx playwright install --with-deps
      - name: Run tests
        run: npx playwright test
        env:
          BASE_URL: ${{ github.event.deployment_status.environment_url }}
```

A GitHub Action that runs an end-to-end test suite using Playwright, testing the Vercel Preview Deployment.

Comment: Can't speak for OP, but at least for me, the use case here isn't running tests, it's using Playwright to take screenshots as part of a monitoring application

Comment: Interesting use case. If it is a part of a monitoring app, it should run as a separate microservice. Under high load, the app will be scaled by adding new instances, which means that Playwright will also be added to every instance. If this is the desired goal, then it is okay. Otherwise, reconsider running Playwright with your app.